# How to dynamically build column name in spark sql withColumn

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have sample data as below.

[image: input]

I would like populate another column `exp` based on `country` field value.

Something like below

```
df.withColumn("exp",col(s"exp_$country"))
```

So that respective `country` number can be placed there.

But above code errors out saying:

> cannot resolve country

Output I need is

[image: 2]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain multiple `when` expressions from the list of countries:

```scala
val countries = Seq("us", "uk", "ind")

val expCol = countries.foldLeft(lit(null)) { case (acc, country) =>
  when(col("country")===country, col(s"exp_$country")).otherwise(acc)
}

val df1 = df.withColumn("exp", expCol)
```

---

Or if you prefer creating a map expression `country -> exp` from the columns `exp_*` than use the map to create `exp` column:

```
val mapCountries = map(
  df.columns
    .filter(_.startsWith("exp_"))
    .flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c.split("_")(1)), col(c))): _*
)

val df1 = df.withColumn("exp", mapCountries(col("country")))
```

Comment: I prefer map option. Because the country list is around ~110. Map option worked for me. Thanks for your help.